# count active users

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security 2.

1.may i know how to use securitycontextholder to get total number of active users?  
2. can retrieve sessionregistry from securitycontextholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to do with spring. But in servlets you need to implement a HttpSession Listener interface for a listener class . The interface has two methods namely sessionCreated() and sessionDestroyed() . Whenever a new session is created you can increment the static variable in the method sessionCreated.

Comment: sessionCreated will be invoked if user hit login page. where i think he needs the active user ,logged in users.

Comment: @org.life.java you create a session on login page or after user authentication is succesfull

Comment: As far as Spring Security is concern this is the proper place  feel to track login event.

Comment: @org i didnt understand this sentence "this is the proper place feel to track login event"

Comment: Sorry I miss spelled in hurry :) , I meant the method from spring filter i have mentioned in my answer i feel this is the proper place to track login event in the system.

Comment: Yours answer is equally true.

Answer (score 3):

extend `AuthenticationProcessingFilter`

override

```
@Override
    protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult)
            throws IOException {
```

and here you can do the things you want to do by keeping a application variable .